# cuda-memcheck : internal error (7)

Tags: cuda

I was trying to debug my CUDA-C program and I found out cuda-memcheck could be helpful. My problem is that I can't use the tool, because everytime I run it, even on an "Hello World" program taken from the internet, I get this result:

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
  *program output*
========= Internal error (7)
========= No CUDA-MEMCHECK results found
```

Here's also a screen of the bash: 
[cuda-memcheck output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKByy.png)

I found nothing on the Internet so I hope someone else here will be able to help me. Thanks anyone!

Comment: this happens sometimes when you have a corrupted CUDA config, for example you are running the `cuda-memcheck` from CUDA 7.5 but have CUDA 8.0 installed.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I installed it from the .run file, and I have already tried reinstalling it. I'll double check it, thx for your answer

Comment: another possible gotcha with `cuda-memcheck` depends on how you run it, exactly, which you haven't shown.  What is the exact command line you are using to launch it?  Have you modified your `PATH` environment variable appropriately?  Are you running `cuda-memcheck` in a directory that you don't have write access to?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I modified my path as cuda post-installation guide said, and I'm generally using it in my git repo folder in documents. I have to say I had other problems with my gpus but it's too long to explain here

Comment: I am seeing this as well on the latest CUDA 8.0. Any updates? This is a new issue for me.

Comment: For me, I am in the nvidia/cuda docker base image, running on AWS K80's, presumably with the latest drivers.

Comment: @RobertCrovella - I am seeing the same error (it's new for me as of today), both cuda-memcheck and nvcc are at v8.0.61.

Comment: @Miles did you manage to solve it? I'm still stuck.

Comment: @Ratacand, sorry, I haven't been able to solve it yet :/

Comment: @Ratacand, are you able to run nvprof on your program successfully? I wonder if this is just a permissions issue like Robert Crovella said.

Comment: Posted an issue on the nvidia-docker page for this: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/454

Comment: @Miles I get `======== Error: unified memory profiling failed.`

Comment: @Miles I now read your issue on nvidia-docker. I managed to make it work by simply calling sudo, but I'm sure it didn't work when I installed it from the Nvidia site .run file. I now upgrade ubuntu version and installed cuda from apt, and it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want post it as an answer, it may help others too

Comment: Thanks, that's great to hear you have it working. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems this is just a permissions issue, as first mentioned in the comments by Robert Crovella. Make sure you have permission to use the relevant `/dev` files, and can see `/dev/nvidia-uvm-tools` there.

For me, this issue came up inside a docker container. I then restarted the container with the privileged flag:

```
nvidia-docker run ... --privilieged ...
```

and this solved my issue entirely. See issue: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/454.

So either running memcheck with:

```
sudo cuda-memcheck ...
```

or trying to reinstall everything with correct permissions and running with sudo should solve this issue (as you found).

One thing that was evident for me was that `cuda-memcheck` ran quite quickly while I executed my program normally. This should not happen: the command can slow your kernels down over 10x, so if you notice the command running at normal speed to regular execution, that is a sign that `cuda-memcheck` can't even get inside your kernels to measure them.